# set min datetime-local input of active date and expire date

Tags: javascript

I want `type="datetime-local"` to show for example 2021-12-28T15:52
"active_date"  should start as the current date and "expire_date" should be after "active_date".

```html
<input type="datetime-local" name="active_date" id="active_date" required/>
<input type="datetime-local" name="expire_date" id="expire_date" required/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`Date.prototype.toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) and [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to have a string formatted `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm` :

```js
let currentDate = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, -8); //yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm
document.querySelector("#active_date").value = currentDate;
document.querySelector("#expire_date").min = currentDate;
```

```html
<input type="datetime-local" name="active_date" id="active_date" required/>
<input type="datetime-local" name="expire_date" id="expire_date" required/>
```